# how to create proper json data format from mysql for highcharts

Tags: php, mysql, json, checkbox, highcharts

I have a json data that will retrive the selected data from database **based on user checked on checkboxes**. but I know my json data is not correct. Tried many way, but still wont works. This is the code:

```
<?php       

        foreach ($_GET['iddoc'] as $iddoc) //iddoc is the value of checked checkbox
        {
            $query="select * from compareresult where iddocument=$iddoc";
            $sql_query = mysql_query($query) or die('Error 3 :'.mysql_error());         
            while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query))
            {
                 $series1['name'][] = $r['subject'];
                 $series1['data'][] = $r['result']; 
            }   
            $jsonTable = json_encode($series1, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); 
            echo $jsonTable; 
        }
```

Based from the code below, lets say if I checked 3 checkbox (BAT123, BIO222, HIS TEST),The json output will be like this:

```
{"name":["BAT123"],"data":[3.03]}
{"name":["BAT123","BIO222"],"data":[3.03,1.05]}
{"name":["BAT123","BIO222","his test"],"data":[3.03,1.05,3.03]}
```

**I know the json above was wrong**, So how to make the json data will be display like this:

```
[
  {"name":["BAT123"],"data":[3.03]},
  {"name":["BIO222"],"data":[1.05]},
  {"name":["his test"],"data":[3.03]}
]
```

This is my highcharts javascript code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
    var data = [
            <?php echo $jsonTable; ?>
        ];
            $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

            chart: {
                renderTo: 'SamHistogramDiv',
                type: 'column',
                marginRight: 130,
                marginBottom: 25
            },
            title: {
                text: 'SAM Histogram Results',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Percentage'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                       return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.x +': '+ this.y;
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -10,
                y: 100,
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: data[0] 

        });
    });
 });
```

Thank u very much for your time..

Comment: @Kapilgopinath the column chart display perfectly..but I have to changed from series: data[0] to series: data .. then the columns show perfectly..but as u know this is not only the value that json will pass to the highcharts, user may checked other value..I dont know why the var data echoing the json not working.. it is just the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with the json data format. It should be like

```
var data = [{name:"BAT123",data:[3.03]},{name:"BIO222",data:[1.05]},{name:"his test",data:[3.03]}];

foreach ($_GET['iddoc'] as $iddoc) //iddoc is the value of checked checkbox
            {
                $query="select * from compareresult where iddocument=$iddoc";
                $sql_query = mysql_query($query) or die('Error 3 :'.mysql_error());         
                while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query))
                {
                  $series[] = array('name'=>$r['subject'],'data'=>array($r['result']));

                }   

            }
$jsonTable = json_encode($series); 
 echo $jsonTable;
```

Pls check if you are getting the json string as mentioned above /* data */

Check this link
http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/Sq3KL/2/

Comment: :) Nice to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   foreach ($_GET['iddoc'] as $iddoc) //iddoc is the value of checked checkbox
            {
                $query="select * from compareresult where iddocument=$iddoc";
                $sql_query = mysql_query($query) or die('Error 3 :'.mysql_error());         
                while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_query))
                {
                     $series[] = array('name'=>$r['subject'],'data'=>$r['result']);

                }   

            }
$jsonTable = json_encode($series); 
 echo $jsonTable;
```

the out put will be like

```
[{"name":"BAT123","data":"3.03"},{"name":"BIO222","data":"1.05"},{"name":"HIs test","data":"1.00"}]
```

Comment: let me know if any issues

Comment: thank u very much dear for your concern, when I run this, the output became like this [{"name":"BAT123","data":"3.03"}][{"name":"BAT123","data":"3.03"},{"name":"BIO222","data":"1.05"}][{"name":"BAT123","data":"3.03"},{"name":"BIO222","data":"1.05"},{"name":"his test","data":"3.03"}].. hehe..

Comment: Place the json encode function outside the foreach loop. :)

Comment: how silly I am..hehe :) kapil do u know how to pass it to highcharts, the json works great. In highcharts, the legend looks good..but the column bar wont came out.. I dont no why.. :(

Comment: give me a screen shot and brief your prob

Comment: aaaa...I cant give u screen shot cause my reputation just 8.. I need 2 reputation more to allows me to send a picture..haha..

Comment: ok, let me check the high chart with your json.Can you provide details about the highchart type used.

Comment: kapil i've just insert the highchart script..the legend works it display what we have checked, but the column like cannot read the json..

Comment: ok Rita, let me give a try. Not sure as I have some restrictions to download plugins.

Comment: I'm very sorry cause I've burden u..thank u very much for your helps..it's ok..I'll try too..